# More efficient way to access multiple database columns

Tags: c#, database, linq-to-sql, c#-4.0, nullable

I'm looking for a more efficient way to build a semicolon delimited list of multiple database columns. The code I'm using right now looks like this (and it works):

```
//Process List of things
var things = DB.DbColumn_1.HasValue ? DB.DbColumn_1.Value.Equals(true) ? "thing 1;" : "" : "");
things += DB.DbColumn_2.HasValue ? DB.DbColumn_2.Value.Equals(true) ? "thing 2;" : "" : "");
things += DB.DbColumn_3.HasValue ? DB.DbColumn_3.Value.Equals(true) ? "thing 3;" : "" : "");
things += DB.DbColumn_4.HasValue ? DB.DbColumn_4.Value.Equals(true) ? "thing 4;" : "" : "");
// Remove final ';' from thing list if non-empty
things = things.Length > 0 ? things.Substring(0, things.Length-1) : things;
```

I actually have about 8 columns to process - the example spares you some of that. So I have a big ugly block of code to build a simple string. Though this seems to work just fine, it seems like too much code for what I'm trying to do. Also, should I be wary of using ".Equals()" in this situation?

After some brainstorming I came up with nothing that seemed any more efficient than this, such as building a separate function to create the string itself. All of the columns are unique nullable bools and all have unique string outputs for the resulting list.

Or am I accessing these elements efficiently enough not to worry about it?

Thank you!

Comment: Flashbacks of The Cat in the Hat. Thing 1 and thing 2...

Comment: You could write one query that gets all the values in one read and then work with the result in linq-to-object to create the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DB.DbColumn_1.HasValue && DB.DbColumn_1.Value.Equals(true)` is a very difficult way of writing `DB.DbColumn_1.GetValueOrDefault()`, but they are functionally equivalent.  See more info on the `Nullable<T>` struct (`bool?` is equivalent to `Nullable<bool>`, which is the type of your DB column) at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s(v=vs.80).aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0.aspx

You can use one of these approaches:

```
var sections = new List<string>();
if (DB.DbColumn_1.GetValueOrDefault()) sections.Add("thing 1");
if (DB.DbColumn_2.GetValueOrDefault()) sections.Add("thing 2");
//...other columns
var things = string.Join(";", sections);
```

Or:

```
var pairs = new List<Tuple<bool?, string>>
{
    Tuple.Create(DB.DbColumn_1, "thing 1"),
    Tuple.Create(DB.DbColumn_2, "thing 2")
    //...other columns
};
var things = string.Join(";", pairs.Where(x => x.Item1.GetValueOrDefault()).Select(x => x.Item2));
```

Or set up `pairs` just once:

```
static readonly List<Tuple<Func<DBType, bool?>, string>> pairs = new List<Tuple<Func<DBType, bool?>, string>>
    {
        new Tuple<Func<DBType, bool?>, string>(d => d.DbColumn_1, "thing 1"),
        new Tuple<Func<DBType, bool?>, string>(d => d.DbColumn_2, "thing 2")
        //...other columns
    };

void inSomeMethod()
{
    var things = string.Join(";", pairs.Where(x => x.Item1(DB).GetValueOrDefault()).Select(x => x.Item2));
}
```

It depends on the circumstances, of course, but I like the last one best.  If the verboseness of the `pairs` declaration bothers you, (i.e. repeating `Tuple<Func<DBType, bool?>, string>`) you can do this:

```
class ReadDbBools : Tuple<Func<DBType, bool?>, string>
{
    public ReadDbBools(Func<DBType, bool?> retrieveFunc, string ifTrue) : base(retrieveFunc, ifTrue) { }
}

static readonly List<ReadDbBools> pairs = new List<ReadDbBools>
{
    new ReadDbBools(d => d.DbColumn_1, "thing 1"),
    new ReadDbBools(d => d.DbColumn_2, "thing 2")
    //...other columns
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You could extend your linq-to-sql model a little bit to return the value you expect, so you got that part out of the way:

```
public partial class Entity {
    public string DbColumn_1_Display {
        return (DbColumn_1 ?? false) ? "thing_1" : "";
    }
    /*for each property*/
}
```

and then for selecting it you can do something like this:

```
var result = from db in DB
             select new { 
                   c1 = DbColumn_1_Display,  
                   c2 = DbColumn_2_Display /*etc*/};
var string = string.Format("{0};{1};{2}/*...*/", result.c1, result.c2 /*...*/);
```

Don't know if this makes things easier.

Answer (score 0):

Well to start with nullable types override the `Equals` method and so instead of this

```
DB.DbColumn_1.HasValue ? DB.DbColumn_1.Value.Equals(true) ? "thing 1;" : "" : ""
```

You can just write this

```
DB.DbColumn_1.Equals(true) ? "thing1;" : ""
```

Also using [`string.Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0.aspx) is a much neater way of handling the extra semicolon at the end, which leaves you with this:

```
var things = string.Join(";", new []
    {
        DB.DbColumn_1.Equals(true) ? "thing1" : null,
        DB.DbColumn_2.Equals(true) ? "thing2" : null,
        // etc...
    }.Where(i => i != null));
```

This makes the code more readable, however won't really do very much to improve performance as this processing should already be pretty quick anyway.